# Streamed videos cache location?

Tags: hard-drive, video, streaming

When i stream games to Youtube via Nvidia Shadowplay - These data are sent directly to server via internet without cahce/temp on my computer? or is there some place where I can find this data on HDD? Basically I wonder when I stream games my HDD is used to save this data before uploading and consumes lifetime of my HDD and I should consider export this cache/temp to independent HDD without important things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not completely sure how shadowplay handles streaming, but from my own experience I know that some temporary files (pretty big, sometimes as much as ~900mb each) are stored and for some reason not deleted from your /AppData/Local/Temp folder. You should notice them easily as they are NOT in a subfolder, and their filenames end with something like 8 digits. You can change that cache folder by going into the GeForce experience overlay and looking in settings.